# Select a non-default sender using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

How can I send from a secondary Outlook account using Excel VBA?

```vb
With OutMail
    .to = Text(1)
    .CC = Text(2)
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject =text(3)
    .HTMLBody = Text(10)
    .Display '.send
End With
```

I tried ".from".

Comment: `Dim acc As Outlook.Account` then Iterate between Outlook `Session.Accounts`: `For Each acc In OLook.Session.Accounts`, where `OLook` is `Outlook.Application`.  Then `If acc.DisplayName = "testaccount@yourdomain.com" Then Set .SendUsingAccount = acc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is from a pretty all-purpose sub I use to send emails from VBA.
It takes three parameters:

- `OutApp` is an `Outlook.Application` object
- `SendFromAddress` is a string variable containing the address to send from
- `OutMail` is the current mailitem object, which you already have as a variable looking at your code.

```
'Sender Address
If Len(SendFromAddress) > 0 Then
    'if directly signed into the account:
    For a = 1 To OutApp.Session.accounts.Count
        If LCase(OutApp.Session.accounts.Item(a)) Like LCase(SendFromAddress) Then
            Outmail.sendusingaccount = OutApp.Session.accounts.Item(a)
            SendFromAddress = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    'If not directly signed in (shared mailbox):
    If Len(SendFromAddress) > 0 Then Outmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = SendFromAddress
End If
```