# Choose from email address when sending?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to choose the correct (1) email address from the list of email addresses I have in Outlook?

How do I edit this working code so I can choose the email address to send from?

Currently I manually select the from email address for 50 emails each week.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub send to multiple persons()
    
    'NOTE: Because YouTube doesn't allow angular brackets 'NOT GREATER THAN' and 'NOT EQUAL TO' have been inserted in the code
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    For Each cell In sh.Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        
        'path/file names are entered in the columns D:M in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1:M1")
        
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            With OutMail
                .TO = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
                .CC = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
                .Subject = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 5).Value
                .Body = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value
                
                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell
                
                '.Send
                .display
            End With
            
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide or list a few of the things you've tried? If only to avoid others answering something you've already heard ...

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73498235/select-a-non-default-sender-using-excel-vba

Comment: Denton Thomas suggestion is similar to what I use. Have you tried it?

Comment: Are you sending on behalf of another Exchange account? Or using a POP3/SMTP account?